# Force Mobile View on Desktop

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Using Rails and Bootstrap 4. I have designed a site solely for Mobile Web for now. So it's optimized for Mobile Browser only. It is responsive though. So on Desktop it looks bigger. How do I force a mobile site to look similar on Desktop?

Here's a sample site that works, but I don't know how it is created: https://www.sorabel.com/

Comment: If it's "designed solely for Mobile Web" then it's not responsive. Responsive means it responds to whatever screen size the user may have.

Comment: not sure who would like to browse a mobile site on desktop, you will be hurting your own brand more then gaining traffic. Having said that. Just put a max width o the body or a content wrapper to be at the mobile breakpoint, center that and you are good to go.

Comment: @Dejan.S Could you put it as an answer with sample code? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so, the title is not quite right but I surely do know what are your referring to. The site you posted is a responsive web site that was made by using media queries.

The key here is to use media queries in order to conserve the width of the content no matter what screen the user is viewing the page. So you would use Responsive breakpoints like these:

```
// Small devices (landscape phones, 576px and up)
@media (min-width: 576px) { ... }

// Medium devices (tablets, 768px and up)
@media (min-width: 768px) { ... }

// Large devices (desktops, 992px and up)
@media (min-width: 992px) { ... }

// Extra large devices (large desktops, 1200px and up)
@media (min-width: 1200px) { ... }
```

NOTE: you can find more of this in Bootstrap documentation here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/overview/#responsive-breakpoints

The most important queries is the desktop one (or if you want the mobile view in tablets you can also use a query for tablets)

Inside the `// Large devices (desktops, 992px and up)` query you would put something like this:

```
// Large devices (desktops, 992px and up)
    @media (min-width: 992px) {
     .mobile-view{
        max-width: 34%;
        padding: 0rem 0px 6.6rem;
        background-color: grey;
     }
 }
```

Then you would just have to add that class `mobile view` in to your main `div`in your html.

```
<div class="mobile-view">
    all your classes and html tags here
</div>
```

Comment: You rock brother

Answer (score 0):

You can add an element that wrapps all of your content. It all depends on how you set it up already but this will be full width in mobile and stick to mobile size once it hits tablet. Once again I need to stress this but I'm not sure if it will be worse on a tablet or a desktop doing this.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.body-wrapper {
  @media (min-width: 768px) {
    max-width: 767px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
}

.header {
  height: 10rem;
  padding: 2rem;
  background-color: aqua;
}
```

```html
<div class="body-wrapper">
  <header class="header"></header>
</div>
```